# Deployment on heroku

Tags: reactjs, github, heroku, web-deployment

I wanna find an email editor web-app like Unlayer on Github.
After some searching I found some React.js projects to clone.After running on localhost, I tried to deploy them on Heroku and Netlify. But It doesn't work.
Does anyone know whether it is possible to deploy a clone project?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtWxN.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbcDg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs in Heroku. It is likely you don't have a Heroku config file or a `start` command in your `package.json` file.

As a sidenote, you might want to have a look at Vercel. Works like Netlify, but it is made by the developers behind Next.js.